# CDI and web fragments: not working without beans.xml

Tags: cdi, jboss-weld, web-fragment

I have three maven projects:

- **core** (packagetype=JAR) with *src/main/resources/beans.xml* bean-discovery-mode="annotated"
- **webfragment** (packagetype=JAR) with *src/main/resources/beans.xml* bean-discovery-mode="annotated"
- **webproject** (packagetype=WAR) with *src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/beans.xml* bean-discovery-mode="annotated"

I have org.jboss.weld.servlet:weld-servlet 2.2.9.Final (CDI 1.2) in my classpath and use a tomcat 7.0.55. Furthermore I use Servlet 3, Deltaspike 1.2.1,  Mojarra 2.2.10.

**All** of my CDI beans have a **bean defining annotation** (see [Meaning of bean discovery mode annotated in CDI 1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310388/meaning-of-bean-discovery-mode-annotated-in-cdi-1-1))

Weld warns me about

> servletWeldServlet [WARN] WELD-ENV-001004: Found both WEB-INF/beans.xml and WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/beans.xml. It's not portable to use both locations at the same time. Weld is going to use jndi:/localhost/webproject/WEB-INF/beans.xml.

but **everything** works fine.

So,  I deleted all beans.xml because I shouldn't need them with CDI 1.2 but afterwards nothing works any longer: **WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies...**

What did I miss? Is this a web fragment problem?

Answer (score 0):

> Unsatisified dependencies at injection point [BackedAnnotatedMethod] or something similar

Shows you at which injection point the resolution failed, check if the type of the injected field is annotated.

That is:

```
@Inject
private SomeService injectedService;
```

Then CDI1.2 mandates that if no beans.xml is defined, it will only scan annotated beans.

Hence

```
@SessionScoped or 
{@ApplicationScoped, @Dependent, @RequestScoped, @ConversationScoped}
public class SomeService{}
```

Comment: Yes, I know. And I import them all from _javax.enterprise.*_ . It's just like as if CDI ignored web fragment JARS without beans.xml.