# @Named @Produces getter not recognized with bean-discovery-mode="annotated"

Tags: jsf, cdi, producer

I am trying to get samples running of the book "Java EE 7 Development with WildFly". Now I face the following question/problem:

TheatreInfo.java:

```
@Model
public class TheatreInfo {
    ...
    @Produces
    @Named
    public Collection<Seat> getSeats() {
        return Lists.newArrayList(seats);
    }
    ...
}
```

Seat.java:

```
@Dependent
@Named
public class Seat {
    ...
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    ...
}
```

index.xhtml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    template="/WEB-INF/templates/default.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">

        <h1>TicketBooker Machine</h1>

        <h:form id="reg">

            <h:panelGrid columns="1" border="1" styleClass="smoke">

                <h:dataTable var="_seat" value="#{seats}" rendered="#{not empty seats}" styleClass="simpletablestyle">

                    ...

                </h:dataTable>

            </h:panelGrid>

        </h:form>

    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

beans.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
    version="1.1" bean-discovery-mode="all/annotated">
</beans>
```

This perfectly works - I see a table of seats in my web-brower - as long as I use bean-discovery-mode="all" in my beans.xml. As soon as I use bean-discovery-mode="annotated" in my beans.xml I don't see the table of seats anymore in my browser respectively I see an empty table but no error occurs.

In the book they use bean-discovery-mode="all" but I prefer to see which classes are managed beans an which are not. To use bean-discovery-mode="annotated" I had to add @Dependent to some classes but I have not been able to fix the issue with the names producer method. Can anyone help?

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310388/meaning-of-bean-discovery-mode-annotated-in-cdi-1-1, it might be useful to you. "*In an implicit archive, CDI can only manage and inject beans annotated with a scope type.*" from http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/cdi-adv001.htm#CACDCFDE

Comment: Thank you for this post. I think my problem ist that the the Return-Type of my producer method is Collection<Seat> which I can not annotate (3th party class) and therefore which is not considered as an injectable bean!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, it runs if I use

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class TheatreInfo {
...
```

instread of

```
@Model
public class TheatreInfo {
...
```

Don't understand why, @Named and @RequestScoped is included in the @Model stereotype!? Does anyone know?

Thanks, Dominic